# Dependent Drop Down List Excel - Unique Values

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I need to connect three lists of data and put them into drop down lists.  So I started by making named ranges, getting all of the unique values and such.

Essentially I followed the instructions on this website:
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/07/17/create-dependent-drop-down-lists-containing-unique-distinct-values-in-excel/

After following the website, I placed these three drop downs all in the same row, one cell apart.  HOWEVER, now I need to have the same three drop down sequence in the next row down.  When I try to do this, the second row is dependent on the values of the first one. So if I pick an initial value for the first row that is not the same initial value as the second row it will not work correctly.

Does anyone see a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, you are creating a unique list for the first drop down box in the first row. The unique list for the second drop down in the first row is dependent upon the value present in your first drop down on the first row. The second list looks for the value you selected in the first drop down of the first row and populates itself with the corresponding values for every instance of the value you picked from the first drop down. This list repopulates and changes every time you select a new value in the first drop down of the first row.

When you are creating the second row, the second drop down is reading from the first row's unique list. There is no unique list based upon the value you have selected in the first drop down of the second row for the second drop down of your second row.

The workaround is to create new lists for the drop downs in the second row.

From your link:

```
 3.Type "=INDEX(product, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, product)+(order<>Sheet1!**$D$2**), 0))"
```

The bolded part is your problem. When you drag this formula, it ties everything to D2 on Sheet1. You will need to make another list using this formula, but change $D$2 to $D$3 or whatever the cell address of your first drop down is for that row.

Comment: Right,thanks for the response. I did try just making the **$D$2** into **D$2** and that did not work either.  I see where you are going but if I need this about 40 times, I should probably think of a new strategy. Correct?

Comment: I don't think so. The first drop downs in every row will operate off of the same list. That will be in column A on Sheet2. Every row will need two distinct lists, one for the second drop down and one for the third. On Sheet2, enter in the row number for the first row of drop downs in row 1 of columns B and C. Enter " =IF(B1-C1=0,C1+1,C1) " into column D and drag across until you get to 40. In row 2 of column B, use the same formula you're using, but change " Sheet1!$D$2 " to " INDIRECT("Sheet1!$D$" & B$1) ". Drag it across to your last column, then drag it down as needed.

Comment: INDIRECT takes a string and turns it into a cell reference. So as you drag across, the value returned by INDIRECRT should be "Sheet1!$D$" and the row number of your drop down. As you drag down, the column and row will not change. Using this, you can create all 80 lists you need in a matter of minutes.

Comment: my first row is 3 for my drop down.  So in B1 and C1 I have 3… Your formula "=IF(B!-C1=0,C1+1,C1) puts 3 in D1.  The objective is to get 4 in that D1 spot?

Comment: Yeah, the pattern should be 2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5... You will need the row number twice

Comment: Also, the INDIRECT function should actually be " INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!$D$" & B$1) ". You Will also need to use CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER when you enter in the INDEX/MATCH function into B2 for the first list. I forgot the single quotes around the sheet name. I set this up, and so far it is working.

Comment: Does this not work for the 3rd drop list though?  So the $D$ will need to go to E to refer to to the next.

Comment: I will probably work on a substitute function within

Comment: Yes, change it to an "E" in column C, then drag both columns B and C. After some testing, I have realized that you will need a blank row in between the headers for the row numbers and the lists. So row 1 contains the 2,2,3,3,4,4... pattern, row 2 is blank, and row 3 is where your lists start. This formula should work in column B: =INDEX(NamedRange1, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(B$2:B2, NamedRange1)+(NamedRange2<>INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!$D$" & B$1)), 0)) and the only changes for it in column C should be replacing NamedRange1 With NamedRange2 and NamedRange2 with NamedRange3 and changing column D to column E.

Comment: You will want it to alternate from D to E. Leaving on the $ and changing it would be better than a substitute function. However, you will need to define ranges for your data validation. What I did was take the data validation string and chop it up everywhere there was a column letter reference. I pasted each piece into a separate column with =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,ROWS(A$1:A1),4),1,"") in between each piece, and then concatenated them all back together in another column. When I drug everything down, I got a list of dynamic ranges to use for data validation.

Comment: sorry i am a bit confused with the data validation named range stuff you did.  So in a separate column you typed in that function, can that separate column be anywhere?  Then you concatenated them all back ?And what do you mean by data validation string? Do you think you could try explaining it again?  Sorry!

Comment: Sorry. When you create the drop down, each one will need it's own range that defines its list to get values from. They are all the same formula with the exception of the column letter, which is the column with that drop down's list on the second sheet that the drop down pulls from. What I did could be done anywhere because it just lets you copy and paste the range when you create the drop down instead of having to edit the range formula each time. It's only temporary scratch work.