# Excel fill drop down list with automated values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have a formula in excel that counts the items in a table by ID of the past few days given by a user.

`=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!J:J,"<"&TODAY()+1,'Sheet1'!B:B,"blocker")-COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!J:J,"<"&TODAY()-F14+1,'Sheet1'!B:B,"blocker")`

Example: 
Enter the amount of past days: 10
blocker = 5

So that being said, the goal I now have is to create a drop down list that grabs the 5 items IDs (blocker) and fills the drop down list with those IDs.

```
id    name          status
231   blocker       NEW
32    normal        ASSIGNED
312   blocker       RESOLVED
```

etc...

The drop down list I would prefer would be the ALT + D + L list as to the active X because it changes the cell's value and I can put conditional formatting on it.

I do know some VBA and I have been scouring for solutions but have yet found any either in excel formula or macros would be nice.

Appreciate all and any help, this is a great community.

-KL

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436389/dependent-drop-down-list-excel-unique-values/24438387#24438387

You will need to have a dynamic list for the drop down to populate from.

Comment: That doesn't give me exactly what I am looking for but Thank you for the suggestion. =)

Comment: Using VBA, you can find the IDs [with an `INDEX` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), store those values in an array, then create a drop-down menu using those items from the array.

Comment: That's just to get you started. If your list values are changing, the easiest thing to do is create a dynamic named range on a hidden sheet that holds your list values, then have that range populate itself based on your entered data using a formula.

In that scenario, the second and third drop downs are populated based on the first and second respectively. Your scenario would be a little bit simpler in that you could use your days input to specify a range limit for the formula that populates your list. The pieces are there, you would just need to rearrange them.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and Idea's I greatly appreciate the feed back.