# VBA - Issues with adding formula for dynamic dependent drop-down

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I'm having a bit of a unique issue with a specific error I can't seem to get around in VBA. What I'm trying to do is add data validation formulas into various cells. These formulas are dynicamic dependent (cascading) drop-downs. I have to enter a formula, rather than raw VBA, as the end-user needs to be able to add items to these lists and have them update immediately.

The issue comes when entering the formula for the dependent validation (second, or greater). When attempting to add these, I receive an error 1004 (Application-Defined error). It appears this is because the formula evaluates to an error, since the cell that this validation is dependent on is currently empty (no selection has been made).

If the formula is added to Data Validation by hand, you receive a popup message about it evaluating to an error, and you can accept it. Rather than this error occurring (which could be handled with Alerts) you get the afore-mentioned 1004 error. Likewise, wrapping error handling around it doesn't do anything - it just makes it so that item isn't filled.

For reference, here is the code snip causing the issue (validation is being added from an array value - this all functions correctly):

```
    'Make changes tied to validation array
For x1 = LBound(selvallist, 2) To UBound(selvallist, 2)

  'Locate cells and add validation
  With builderwb.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Find(selvallist(3, x1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=selvallist(4, x1)
  End With
Next x1
```

Here is the formula being added:

```
=OFFSET(Anchor, 1, MATCH(V2, GenReason, 0)-1, COUNTA(OFFSET(Anchor, , MATCH(V2, GenReason, 0)-1, 50, 1))-1, 1)
```

Here is the message that appears when adding it by hand:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDMmI.png)

Any help is appreciated. I may be able to technically set the cells these are dependent on with a value first, then clear them - this seems like an ugly solution, and it isn't particularly easy however, as all of my formulas are dynamic named ranges.

This is also posted: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/938761-visual-basic-applications-error-handling-adding-data-validation-dynamic-drop-downs-programmatically.html

Comment: Is your question like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436389/dependent-drop-down-list-excel-unique-values/24438387#24438387

Comment: @asp8811, not quite. That is trying to get the formula to work - my formula works fine, its just that if entered without a value in the first cell, it will default to an error. When entering it by hand, as that person is trying to do, you can just override it (as it actually works, in practice). I need to find a way to override it in VB, as it throws a 1004 error.

Comment: Why do you need to enter the data validation in VBA? If you duplicate what that person did, you could accomplish your dynamic dependent dropdowns fairly quickly. Is this something that you will need to build a lot? ETA: There is also a discussion in the comments on my answer about replication the formulas needed to support the lists.

Comment: @asp8811 it has to be entered into VBA due to what the file function is - essentially, I have a master document with 60+ tabs related to various job roles. Then I have a secondary document that the user can choose whatever role they need and it will build out a template dynamically for the user. Users can do this several times a week. Technically, I could make each role's main sheet be separate rather than building dynamically, however this would add another 20+ sheets to maintain in the file so I'd prefer not to. I was wondering instead if there was an actual fix to this issue.

Comment: Got it. Can you build the formula as a string? Use something like .Formula1="=Something (something(x1))" and just recreate it a few times? I think trying to add the list as an array might be your problem.